# How to fill a web form and submit it with CefSharp

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm trying to use CefSharp, seems to work fine for now.

I want to fill a form(which is a login form) and submit the form, any idea how I can do this?

I've found there is an `ExecuteScriptAsync`, but this use JavaScript(I guess a script that should be existing on the page, right?)

Thank you!

Comment: "I guess a script that should be existing on the page, right?". No, you can execute any JavaScript you want, it doesn't have to exist in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JavaScript. Please Take a look on Documentation https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#CallJS

Another Good Example [Trying to simulate user inputs in CefSharp3 (OffScreen) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587322/trying-to-simulate-user-inputs-in-cefsharp3-offscreen-using-javascript)