# Trying to simulate user inputs in CefSharp3 (OffScreen) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, web, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am trying to simulate the user operation on CefSharp(OffScreen) using JavaScript.

Once I load the page (https://www.w3.org),
*I am trying to search in the search bar,

click the search button

open first result*

So I have used,

```
            await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value = 'CSS';");
            await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('search-submit').click();");
            await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('r1-0').click();");
```

But the issue I am facing is, to take screenshot, I have to use **Thread.Sleep(x)** in between and at the end for the pages to load before doing the next operation or take the screenshot.

Is there anyway to avoid the **SLEEP** and detect when the loading is done, to do the next operation?

I tried **ExecuteScriptAsync** also, same issue with that also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify and use the **LoadPageAsync()** function from the *OffScreenExample* for this purpose.
Just replace alter the parameters by removing the *url* as you wont be using it, and remove the if statement using the *url*.
Then on calling the **LoadPageAsync** after **EvaluateScriptAsync** with the corresponding *browser* object.

The Function will look like this after modification.

```
public static Task LoadPageAsync(IWebBrowser browser)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    EventHandler<LoadingStateChangedEventArgs> handler = null;
    handler = (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (!args.IsLoading)
        {
            browser.LoadingStateChanged -= handler;
            tcs.TrySetResultAsync(true);
        }
    };

    browser.LoadingStateChanged += handler;
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Usage will be like,

```
await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value = 'CSS';");
await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('search-submit').click();");
await LoadPageAsyncCompleted(browser);
await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('r1-0').click();");
await LoadPageAsyncCompleted(browser);
```